# Add path in TeX Live 2012 on Ubuntu

Tags: packages, texlive, ubuntu, paths

I write a package named `umtools.sty`,
since Ubuntu One can only sync the folder which is in `~/`,
so I put `*.sty` in `~/tlpkg/`.

Now, how can I use it like `\usepackage{umtools}` instead of `\usepackage{~/tlpkg/umtools}`,
as the way it is set up, `\usepackage{<absolute path>}` causes a warning:
"You have requested package `~/tlpkg/umtools', but the package provides umtool",
which makes me uncomfortable.

I've tried to modify `~/.pam_environment` to add new PATH, but it doesn't work.
Does someone know kpathsea.

Ubuntu 13.04 + Tex Live 2012 by sh install_tl + TeXstudio + XeTeX

Comment: `mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex && mv ~/tlpkg/umtools.sty ~/texmf/tex/latex/`.  `~/texmf` is the proper local/personal directory; but make it mimic a proper 'tex tree' directory structure.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Please [Read The Fine Manual](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-370003.4.6).

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. Put them in a standard directory where TeX will look:

   `~/texmf/tex/latex/umtools`

   You may need to run `texhash` afterwards.
2. Set the env. variable `TEXINPUTS`. (just like you'd set `$PATH`). I prefer to set it to something like this:

   `TEXINPUTS=.:./packages:$HOME/texmf`

   which gives me the flexibility of what package to use for a project:

   1. First check in the current working directory (for small projects)
   2. Then check in the sub directory `packages`
   3. Then check in `~/texmf`
   4. And finally use the distribution default package.

Comment: TeX Live 2012 doesn't require `texhash` on your 'local' tree unless it's on a remote file system.

Comment: I needed to append a trailing colon (`:`) to `TEXINPUTS`, otherwise the default locations were not searched.